# No usernames on leaderboard for Hat Dash

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2020, hat-dash

I think the screenshot says it all:

[image]

There are no usernames on the leaderboard, so we don't know who is the best at show jumping their unicorn.

Comment: Currently I do see avatars and usernames. I played a few more games since then. Could that be the trigger?

Comment: I see them now, and I haven't played the game at all. It was probably just a bug that got fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now

> two items added
> sharing single key value
> many errors logged